# Case insensitive package installation (ignore case) while installing packages

Tags: r, package, case-insensitive, install.packages, ignore-case

Is there any way to ignore the case or turn on the case insensitivity while installing packages.

Example, `RWeka` package. Is it possible to install it like `install.packages("rweka")` or somehow setting the `ignore.case = TRUE`, but there is no argument like that to `install.packages()`

Comment: Theoretically there could be two packages RWeka and rweka (although CRAN would not allow that). However, you should not need that.

Answer (score 3):

Package names are case sensitive. Therefore you may not get a unique match if you ignore the case. Having said that, the best way to achieve what you want is:

```
#get list of packages
packages <- available.packages()[,"Package"]
#find matches by ignoring case
my_packs <- packages[grep("^rweka$",packages,ignore.case=TRUE)]
#install - beware of multiple matches
install.packages(my_packs)
```

Note the regexp in `grep` specifies the start and end of the string, otherwise you might end up with even more packages that contain what you want as a sub-string.

Answer (score 1):

You can augment R with:

```
install_p <- function(x) {
  av <- available.packages()
  av <- setNames(av[,"Package"], tolower(av[,"Package"]))
  install.packages(av[x])
}
```

in your `~/.Rprofile` and it will be safe to do:

```
install_p("rweka")
```

since:

```
sum(duplicated(tolower(unname(av[,"Package"]))))
```

is `0` as Roland noted in his comment.

CRAN *may* loosen their own internal policies as the volume of R packages grows (it's near 10K now) but I suspect they'd still not allow matching names.